# Unwanted sorting MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sorting, subquery

So I have two tables in MySQL database: 
Table `students` and `enrollment`. Each one has their `id` column and `enrollment.student_id` links to `student.id`.
I have a list of enrollment ids which I'm passing to this query using `python`.  I'm trying to get the names of the students which are enrolled in a class.

```
ids = (414,415,416,417)

query = """SELECT name FROM student WHERE id IN 
           (SELECT student_id FROM enrollment WHERE id IN {} )""".format(ids)

cursor.execute(query)
```

If pass `enrollment.id = (414,415,416,417)`, the result I was expecting was something like a set of `student.id = (25, 7, 14, 3)`. This is the correct order that I want, `enrollment.id=414` corresponds to `student.id=25` and so on, which in turn gives the student names.

For some reason the subquery sorts the result of `student.id` to `(3, 7, 14, 25)` and then queries the names, thus giving me the incorrect sequence.
How can I keep MySQL from sorting that subquery?

I figured I could do a workaround that by using a loop and query each enrollment individually, but I still wondered if this would have a solution.

Comment: There's no "correct sequence" when you don't use `ORDER BY` to specify the sorting. What prevents you from doing `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that the link is `student.id=enrollment.student_id`, then one solution you can try is by joining the tables instead, then add `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT student.name FROM student JOIN enrollment 
   ON student.id=enrollment.student_id
   WHERE enrollment.id IN {} 
ORDER BY enrollment.id
```